# Flutter: Adding background image with image picker

Tags: flutter, dart

so I have a simple question that I can't seem to figure out after a lot of trying out different things. So I have this ImagePicker Flutter function that picks image from gallery. I want to be able to click button to change background of the whole screen. Here is the function for Image Picker and it works fine.

```
Future _getImage() async {
final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
setState(() {
  if (pickedFile != null) {
    _image = File(pickedFile.path);
    
    print('_image: $_image');
  } else {
    print('No image selected');
  }
});
```

}

The issue is that I can't seem to add that picked image in the BoxDecoration in the Scaffold, there is always an error, something in the vein of: 'The argument type 'Image' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider'

```
body: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      image: DecorationImage(
        image: Image(_image),
      ),
    ),
```

I tried converting to string, linking direct path, but nothing seems to work. Is there a workaround around this or is there some other simple solution? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can check `_image == null` and to show `TransparentImage` or `FileImage` 
code snippet

```
import 'package:transparent_image/transparent_image.dart';
...
body: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: _image == null
              ? MemoryImage(kTransparentImage)
              : FileImage(_image),
        ),
      )),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:transparent_image/transparent_image.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  File _image;
  final picker = ImagePicker();

  Future _getImage() async {
    final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    setState(() {
      if (pickedFile != null) {
        _image = File(pickedFile.path);

        print('_image: $_image');
      } else {
        print('No image selected');
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: _image == null
              ? MemoryImage(kTransparentImage)
              : FileImage(_image),
        ),
      )),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _getImage,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow, that is a very nice workaround. Your effort is very much appreciated!

Comment: Glad to help. please mark this as answer if it helps you. thanks

Answer (score 0):

please try this ...

```
        Container(
                width: 100,
                height: 200,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image:DecorationImage(
                    image: new FileImage(file)
                  )
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: Wow, that's a very elegant solution, I didn't know there was a FileImage option. I appreciate your answer a lot, you saved me a lot of headache!